# Infinitesimal Conical Frustum Surface

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

[image]

The formula for the lateral surface of a conical frustum is :

[image]

Now, let's consider an infinitesimal conical frustum (we can use it to derive the surface of a cone for example).
For $h\rightarrow 0$ , $R_{1}\approx R_{2}$ so $(R_{1} - R_{2})^{2} \rightarrow 0$ and the surface of an infinitesimal conical frustum would be $2\pi R_{2}\,dh$, however i was told that it's not correct. Why?

ps: incredibly this approximation is correct in the case i want to calculate the volume of a cone but not for the surface... :S

[image]

Comment: wtf is an infinitesimal conical frustum?  Is this nonstandard analysis?

Comment: You can't mix an informal treatment of infinitesimals with $(R_1-R_2)^2\to 0$.  Even when a similar method works (it's not guaranteed in this informal context), you need to consider the rate of convergence to zero.

Comment: The problem is you haven't accounted properly for the dependence of $R_2$ on $R_1$ and $h$. For frustrums of a fixed cone, they have a fixed relationship, and you are violating that relationship in your calculation. But while I could take you through it step by step, I have to ask, what is even the point? Just set $R_2 = 0$ in your frustrum formula and you get the surface area of a cone of base radius $R_1$ and height $h$. The hard part was coming up with the frustrum formula in the first place.